# Gather statistics on materialized views as part of gather_schema_stats

Tags: oracle, statistics, materialized-views

We use the following to refresh statistics for all tables in a given schema:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(ownname => 'some_schema', estimate_percent => dbms_stats.auto_sample_size, cascade => true, method_opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO', degree => 12);
```

This however, sets row-counts for our materialized views to zero and has the unwanted side effect of causing inefficient query plans for queries against materialized views. We work around this by gathering table stats against the specific mviews after the schema stats have run.

My question is: can I change the parameters to gather_schema_stats in any way that will cause mview row-counts not to be set to zero?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell `GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS` to exclude certain objects.  You could do a `GATHER STALE` to gather statistics only on the objects where statistics are stale but it is entirely possible that would include your materialized views.  A few ways to work around that

1) Use the `LOCK_TABLE_STATS` procedure to lock the statistics on your materialized views.  That will prevent `GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS` from gathering statistics on those objects until you call the `UNLOCK_TABLE_STATS` procedure (presumably as part of the process that refreshes the materialized view statistics periodically).

2) Use the `EXPORT_TABLE_STATS` procedure to save the statistics for the materialized views before gathering schema statistics and then call `RESTORE_TABLE_STATS` after the `GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS` call completes to put the materialized view statistics back.

3) Don't use `GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS`.  Call `GATHER_TABLE_STATS` in a loop where you exclude whatever objects you want.  Something like

```
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT *
              FROM dba_tables
             WHERE owner = 'SOME_SCHEMA'
               AND table_name NOT IN (<<list of MVs>>))
  LOOP
     dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( x.owner, x.table_name, ... );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Many thanks. I hadn't heard of lock_table_stats. It turned out it wasn't gather_schema_stats that was resetting the mview stats. It was dbms_snapshot.refresh. We'll just lock the mview stats before any refreshes.